# KineticJS setText method to update like a Timer

Tags: html, text, canvas, timer, kineticjs

I need to update the text property of a KineticJS text like a timer. but my below code doent work as expected, what I am doing wrong:

```
var dateTimeText = new Kinetic.Text({
            x: 40,
            y: 400,
            text: "Sample",
            fontSize: 18,
            width: 700,
            fontFamily: 'Calibri',
            fill: 'black',
            width: 700,
            padding: 10,
            align: 'right',
            draggable: true
        });
setInterval(function () { onUpdateTime() }, 1000);
        function onUpdateTime() {
            var date = new Date();
            dateTimeText.setText(date.toLocaleTimeString());
        }
```

In the onUpdateTime(), should I do manipulations on dateTimeText. When adding the draggable attribute on dateTimeText() and when clicking on it, i can atleast see the updated value :)

Comment: Just some questions to understand this better: ...What is the outcome/what doesnt work? what should happen , and what does happen?

Comment: @winner_joiner I have added the current implemnetation in the link. Outcome: The Text should update the "Sample" text value based on current time. What happens now: No change in the text value(unless mouse click on the text)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
    function onUpdateTime() {
        var date = new Date();
        dateTimeText.setText(date.toLocaleTimeString());
        // layer.draw(); // either this, or whatever the layer is called
        // dateTimeText.getParent().draw(); // or this, auto get parent layer
        dateTimeText.getLayer().draw(); // better solution suggested by Eric Rowell
    }
```

Comment: a common thing to forget is to redraw the layer.

Comment: you could also create an animation, which updates the text object, and an animation automatically redraws the layer.

Comment: also, rather than assuming that the parent of the Text shape is the layer (it might be a group) it's better to do use dateTimeText.getLayer().draw() instead

Comment: @EliteOctagon : Thanks for the solution, almost all the time I forget to redraw the layer.

Comment: @EricRowell : You are correct regarding the parent of text object :), it is a group in my app. After updating the above step (with layer redraw) in my app I could see huge flickering in my custom shape object (Graph control), when redrawing layer. So i changed the text object to a group instead of directly on the layer.

Comment: True, I forget about groups sometimes.